# 'in his dreary cry' or 'from his dreary cry'

Tags: word-usage, difference

Should I use 'in' or 'from' in the next line:
"Every time the wolf is calling and rain falls from the sky I know I must heed the warning in/from his dreary cry".

Answer (score 1):

Either could be grammatically correct, but if the wolf's cry *is* a warning, then you should use 'in'.

When someone speaks, the things they explicitly said or intended to convey would be said to be *in* their words, but you may extract other things *from* their words, or even their tone of voice.

Comment: Thank you, Astralbee! This makes it very clear.